# Error con espacios y tabs / Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces

Tags: python

Me aparece este error: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation in line (' if value == letra: ')

```
def desencriptar(mensaje):
    palabras = mensaje.split(' ')
    mensaje_descifrado = []

    for palabra in palabras:
        palabra_descifrada = ''
        for letra in palabra:
            for key, value in KEYS.items():
            if value == letra:
            palabra_descifrada += key
    mensaje_descifrado.append(palabra_descifrada)
    return ' '.join(mensaje_descifrado)
```

Cual puede ser el problema?? Muchas gracias

Comment: En python no puedes mezclar tabs y espacios al mismo tiempo para marcar la identación. Revisa con un editor que te muestre los caracteres ocultos y usa un único criterio para esto.

Comment: Que editor puede mostrar caracteres ocultos? Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Hoy en día casi todos te lo permiten, de los que conozco, notepad++ o vim lo tienen, hay que buscar la opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que has combinado dos tipos de teclas al momento de dar espacios(eso depende como este configurado tu editor de código).

> Por ejemplo en esta imagen capturada en **sublime text 3**, puedes ver
>   que la identación es correcta utilizando **puntos consecutivos** para
>   dar espacio a cada linea(fíjate los puntos al lado izquierdo del
>   código):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Aquí otro ejemplo de una buena identacion esta vez en forma de
>   lineas(esto en sublime se realiza con la tecla tab o tabuladora), esto
>   es correcto para una lectura en python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Por ultimo este código presenta un problema de identación al haber
>   **combinado dos tipos de espacios** (la tecla tab  con la tecla espacio)
>   fíjate en la lineas del codigo:`if value == letra` que es ahí donde
>   obtienes el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes utilizar el editor **Sublime Text 3** para poder ver las identaciones en tus códigos. Puedes descargar Sublime desde su sitio oficial: https://www.sublimetext.com/3

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si te solucionó tu pregunta puedas calificarla como resulta.